# NetworkX MultiDiGraph paths not distinguishing parallel edges

Tags: python, networkx

If I have a very simple directed multigraph

```py
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_edge('A', 'B', key=1)
G.add_edge('B', 'C', key=2)
G.add_edge('B', 'C', key=3)

--

(A) -1- (B) -2- (C)
            \3/
```

I would expect `nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source='A', target='C')` to return 
two paths;

- `A-1-B-2-C`
- `A-1-B-3-C`

but (as it's currently implemented) `all_shortest_paths` just returns the nodes, not the nodes and edges so we only get one path;

```
>>> list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, source='A', target='C'))
[['A', 'B', 'C']]
```

Is there any simple / generic method for returning actual paths, rather than simple node lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`networkx` has no built-in functions to handle it so you have to do everything manually.

`nx.all_simple_paths()` returns node lists so for MultiDiGraph there will be many repetitions. So firstly we remove them by converting the `nx.all_simple_paths()` output to `set` and then iterate for it. For every path we extract node pairs (for example: `[1,2,3,4] -> [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]`) and for each pair we get `AtlasView` of all edges between them. Here is the code for this algorithm:

```
import networkx as nx
from pprint import pprint

# Create the graph with unique edges to check the algorithm correctness
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    [1,2],
    [1,2],
    [1,2],
    [2,3],
    [2,3],
    [2,3],
    [3,4],
    [3,4],
    [2,4]
])
G.add_edge(1,2,data='WAKA')
G.add_edge(2,3,data='WAKKA')
G.add_edge(2,4,data='WAKA-WAKA')

# Our source and destination nodes
source = 1
destination = 4

# All unique single paths, like in nx.DiGraph
unique_single_paths = set(
    tuple(path)  # Sets can't be used with lists because they are not hashable
    for path in nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, destination)
)

combined_single_paths = []
for path in unique_single_paths:
    # Get all node pairs in path:
    # [1,2,3,4] -> [[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]]
    pairs = [path[i: i + 2] for i in range(len(path)-1)]

    # Construct the combined list for path
    combined_single_paths.append([
        (pair, G[pair[0]][pair[1]])  # Pair and all node between these nodes
        for pair in pairs
    ])
pprint(combined_single_paths)
```

```
[[((1, 2), AtlasView({0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {'data': 'WAKA'}})),
  ((2, 3), AtlasView({0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {'data': 'WAKKA'}})),
  ((3, 4), AtlasView({0: {}, 1: {}}))],
 [((1, 2), AtlasView({0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {'data': 'WAKA'}})),
  ((2, 4), AtlasView({0: {}, 1: {'data': 'WAKA-WAKA'}}))]]
```

Comment: Thanks - what I actually want explodes the `combined_single_paths`, but this gets me 90% of the way there. Also, I think `[path[i: i + 2] for i in range(len(path)-1)]` can be `nx.utils.misc.pairwise(path)` if you enjoy python golf.

Comment: Wow, cool, thank you for this function! I havent't known about it!

Comment: Hi danodonovan and vurmux. I too am looking to determine multiple paths between source and target. Could you please share how you modified the above code by vurmux to list 2 paths, i.e. A-1-B-2-C and A-1-B-3-C between A and C. I'll really appreciate your help. Have been stuck on this for more than a week now.